# Turn off audio playback of AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, avplayer

I have a AVPlayer with AVPlayerItem. What i want is to turn off the audio playback off AVPlayer. I want play just video.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
    self.avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:self.videoUrl];
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.avPlayerItem];
    [self.avPlayer play];
    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;


    self.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
    self.avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidPlayToEndTime:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:self.avPlayerItem];


    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width , screenRect.size.height );
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.avPlayerLayer atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AVPlayer have option

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isMuted) BOOL muted NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 7_0);
```

You can write

```
- (void) muteSound:(BOOL)mute
{
    self.avPlayer.muted = mute;
}
```

And use it, how you want

```
- (void) startPlayingVideo
{

    [self muteSound:YES];

    //other code

}
```

Comment: for swift 5 it is just: player.isMuted = true before calling .play() ;)

Answer (score 46):

As @Tung Fam's answer suggests, you can easily do this in your App to mute a video-

`player.isMuted = true`

**Handling all the Use Cases:**

You may run a video on mute using the code above, the problem is, if you simply use `isMuted = true` (for let's say the video preview) it will work, but your app will "hijack" the `AVAudioSession` from the Operating system, which means if the user was, lets say, listening to music (spotify or apple music), their music would get interrupted. That is because your App will have a default setup of `AVAudioSession` to `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` , which means that **your app will ALWAYS interrupt all audio sessions that is running in the background as soon as it starts playing a video, muted or un-muted**. This may not be a very pleasing user experience and lead to confusion.

What you may want to do is, show your video muted as a preview, while the user continues to play their song in the background. When user goes to full screen with your app's video, any background audio must "pause" or be "interrupted" essentially your app taking over the `AVAudioSession`. And then once you are done playing your video let the "interrupted" background music (example: Spotify, Apple Music etc.) to resume. The steps below achieves exactly how Twitter's app handles videos and background music-

1. In your AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method make sure your app is not interrupting any background music. Now since your videos would be running in "mute" you can simply `mixWithOthers`.

   ```
     do{
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, options: [.mixWithOthers])
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }catch{//some meaningful exception handling}
   ```
2. When your App starts to play your video Full screen (un-muted/with sound), you must now interrupt any background music. For that, before your `player.play()` you can set the `AVAudioSession` again, like so-

   ```
    do{
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
     }catch{//some meaningful exception handling}
   ```

this will basically pause/interrupt any background audio in progress and let your video play with sound.

3. Once your video is done playing with sound, you must now let the `AVAudioSession` know that it can resume any audio session that was interrupted by you (i.e. Spotify, apple music, map navigation instructions etc.). To do that, once your video stops playing you can do this-

   ```
    do{
          try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, options: [.mixWithOthers])
          try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
       }catch{//some meaningful exception handling}
   ```

There's a lot more options available on how to handle `AVAudioSession` and [here's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession) the documentation. And [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioGuidelinesByAppType/AudioGuidelinesByAppType.html) are Apple's guidelines on using `AVAudioSession` for different type of apps.

---

This is just a very basic explanation on how `AVAudioSession` can be used, but depending on your app's functionality there may be a need to use KVOs, AppDelegate methods (for app going to background and or coming to foreground and so on) to set the `AVAudioSession` appropriately. Further caveat is that you really need to play around with all the options on `AVAudioSession` since it may not work the way you think it should so it could become a little grueling. Even more caveat is that surprisingly i've found very little online that goes into detail with `AVAudioSession` except for Apple's documentation and a few questions here on SO here and there. Bottom line is - if your app deals with Audio/Videos then it is HIGHLY recommended to handle `AVAudioSession` appropriately based on Apple's playbook of "[Audio Guidelines By App Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioGuidelinesByAppType/AudioGuidelinesByAppType.html)", maybe not when you launch your app but definitely as your app matures and becomes more stable.

Comment: This answer is great, Thank you :)

Comment: The API for this is now `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: [AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers])`

Comment: Is it necessary to call setActive(true) after making category/option changes?

Comment: There is only one problem with mixWithOthers - it disables Control Center functionality if you use it :(. If you enable mixWithOthers, you won't be able to display your information in Media Player in Control Center...

Comment: Well, Is this that of what Facebook does? Thx xD

Comment: @KoreanXcodeWorker I am not entirely sure about Facebook. But Twitter definitely does this.

Comment: @WojciechKulik +1, As I mentioned in my answer, there are a whole host of things that needs to be looked into when dealing with `AVAudioSession`; control center is one of them. Unfortunately, I am far from iOS development at the moment, so I can't shed too much light on this.

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is looking for **Swift 4**:

```
player.isMuted = true // To mute the sound
player.isMuted = false // To un-mute the sound
```

Side note: muting the video does not reset the video sound to start. It works as just a common sense mute feature.

Comment: One small problem- if the user is playing a song (Spotify or Apple Music etc) in the background then the AVPlayer will take over the soundtrack and pause the music that is playing in the background

Comment: @Annjawn hm interesting. but I'm wondering. if you play sound on your app do you want the other sound to be on the back, or should it be paused?

Comment: It should be paused and it should resume again when your apps video stops. Checkout Twitter’s implementation.

Comment: @Annjawn checked, yeah they did a good job. do you know the way how to make the same? or do you mean that we shouldn't use `isMuted` property in this case?

Comment: i have a fair idea of how to achieve it... (got the idea from a Twitter Engineer himself :-) ). I am going to post an answer with the code shortly.

Comment: Also, using `isMuted` is correct, to achieve the way twitter handles we will have to put just a little bit more code.

Comment: @Annjawn gotcha:) looking forward to seeing your solution!

Comment: posted the answer.

Comment: How could we "delete" or deactivate the music so that when tunred on it does not overlap with other music?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. If you don't want your video to stop the sound that is currently played on other apps (even if your video player is set to mute)

```
func setAudioMix(){
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }catch{
        print("something went wrong")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  This will keep the background music playing.

Answer (score -1):

You can mute the audio by implementing following code into `viewDidLoad()`.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self myAssetURL] 
options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]; 

// Mute all the audio 
tracksNSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];

for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {    
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams 
=[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];   

[audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];  

[audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];    [allAudioParams 
addObject:audioInputParams];}

AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = 
[AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];
```

Following links may help you.

1. https://goo.gl/WYJNUF
2. https://goo.gl/epHNGs